# Create join table with Elixir and Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have `Users` and `Leagues` and then a join table `users_leagues`. The goal of what I'm trying do is simple create the join when creating a new league. Here are my models:

#### LEAGUE:

```
defmodule Statcasters.League do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "leagues" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :teams, Statcasters.Teams.Team
    has_many :users_leagues, Statcasters.UsersLeagues
    has_many :users, through: [:users_leagues, :user]


    timestamps()
  end
end
```

#### USER:

```
defmodule Statcasters.Coherence.User do
  @moduledoc false
  use Ecto.Schema
  use Coherence.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    coherence_schema()
    has_many :teams, Statcasters.Teams.Team
    has_many :users_leagues, Statcasters.UsersLeagues
    has_many :leagues, through: [:users_leagues, :league]

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

#### USERS_LEAGUES:

```
defmodule Statcasters.UsersLeagues do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "users_leagues" do
    field :commissioner, :string
    belongs_to :league, Statcasters.League
    belongs_to :user, Statcasters.Coherence.User

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

#### LEAGUE CONTROLLER:

```
def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = %League{}
      |> League.changeset()

    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"league" => league_params}) do
    user = Repo.get!(User, conn.assigns.current_user.id)

    league = %League{}
      |> League.changeset(league_params)
      |> Repo.insert()

    case league do
      {:ok, league} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "League Created Successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
end
```

So basically on create of league I'd also like to create the join table between user and league. What is the "Phoenix Way" of doing this?

Comment: First you remove it out of the controllers and let them handle only web specific logic. Then, in the appropriate core module, you start a transaction and create a league and if that's successful, you create the join table.

Comment: What is the advantage of posting a sheet of boilerplate code?

Comment: @mudasobwa Hoping it would give some insight on the logic of the app and ruling out wrong assumptions that I set it up correctly.

Comment: @JustMichael Oh interesting... That sounds good!

Comment: @JustMichael any chance you can post an example of how that would look. I'm still struggling to get this working.